# Fitting code and formulas together and aligned

Tags: beamer, equations, listings

Here is a slide from a presentation I'm preparing:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]{Example}
\begin{tabular}{ l r }
\begin{lstlisting}[mathescape=true]
harness void main(int x){
int y = x * ??$_0$;
assert y == x + x;
}
\end{lstlisting} & 
\begin{minipage}{.8\textwidth}
    $\phi:\{(??_0,\tau_{\emptyset}) \} \to \mathbb{Z}$. \newline
    $y \equiv \lambda \phi. x * \phi(??_0,\tau_{\emptyset})$ 
\end{minipage}%
 \\ \hline
\begin{lstlisting}[mathescape=true]
generator int linexp(int t){
 return t * ??$_0$ + ??$_1$ ;
}

generator int 
 linexp2(int t1, int t2){
 return linexp$_{g1}$(t1) + 
        linexp$_{g2}$(t2);
}

void main(int x, int z){
 int y = linexp2$_{g0}$(x, z);
 assert y == x + x + z;
}   
\end{lstlisting} &  
\begin{minipage}{.9\textwidth}
    $\tau_1 = g_0 \cdot g_1, \tau_2 = g_0 \cdot g_2$ \\
    $\phi:\{(??_0,\tau_1),(??_0,\tau_2), 
            (??_1,\tau_1),(??_1,\tau_2) \} \to \mathbb{Z}$ \\
    $y \equiv \lambda \phi. x * \phi(??_0,\tau_1) + \phi(??_1,\tau_1) 
       + z * \phi(??_0,\tau_2) + \phi(??_1,\tau_2)$ 
\end{minipage}%
\end{tabular}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

How can I get the text to the right to be aligned properly. Something like:

[image]

Comment: I also appreciate any comments on the style

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use `aligned` environments for the math material, and I'd use a lot more line breaks in the second math group. I would also use `\colon` instead of `:`, as the latter is treated by default as a relational operator, which doesn't seem to be the case here.

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]{Example}
\begin{tabular}{@{} ll @{}}
\begin{lstlisting}[mathescape=true]
harness void main(int x){
int y = x * ??$_0$;
assert y == x + x;
}
\end{lstlisting} & 
$\begin{aligned}
&\phi\colon\{(??_0,\tau_{\emptyset}) \} \to \mathbb{Z} \\
&y \equiv \lambda \phi\cdot x * \phi(??_0,\tau_{\emptyset})
\end{aligned}$ \\ 
\hline
\begin{lstlisting}[mathescape=true]
generator int linexp(int t){
 return t * ??$_0$ + ??$_1$ ;
}

generator int 
 linexp2(int t1, int t2){
 return linexp$_{g1}$(t1) + 
        linexp$_{g2}$(t2);
}

void main(int x, int z){
 int y = linexp2$_{g0}$(x, z);
 assert y == x + x + z;
}   
\end{lstlisting} &  
$\begin{aligned}
&\tau_1 = g_0 \cdot g_1,\\
&\tau_2 = g_0 \cdot g_2, \\
&\phi\colon\{(??_0,\tau_1),(??_0,\tau_2), \\
&\qquad(??_1,\tau_1),(??_1,\tau_2) \} \to \mathbb{Z} \\
&y \equiv \lambda \phi\cdot x * \phi(??_0,\tau_1) \\
&\qquad+ \phi(??_1,\tau_1) \\
&\qquad+ z * \phi(??_0,\tau_2) \\
&\qquad+ \phi(??_1,\tau_2)
\end{aligned}$
\end{tabular}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```